# Multiple create models in one razor view (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have multiple `create` forms in my view and they always send null data to the controller.

Here's my code
View model:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Device> devicelist { get; set; }
    public Process proclist { get; set; }
    public Extratime extras { get; set; }
    public Foodadd foods { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        devicelist = new List<Device>();
        proclist = new Process();
        extras = new Extratime();
        foods = new Foodadd();
    }
}
```

And one of the forms in my view which always sends null data:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="AddTime" style="direction: rtl;">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.proclist.DeviceId" value="@item.Id" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.proclist.Userid" value="@currentUser.Id" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <select asp-for="@Model.proclist.IsLimited" class="form-control" id="cc">
            <option value="true">limited</option>
            <option value="false">Open</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="pp">
        <input type="number" asp-for="@Model.proclist.hours" class="form-control home" placeholder="1.5" step=".01">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select asp-for="@Model.proclist.IsSingle" class="form-control">
            <option value="true">single</option>
            <option value="false">multi</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enable</button>
</form>
```

That's what my controller expects from my view ( returns a NullReferenceException for the lack of data from the view. ):

```
public IActionResult AddTime(Process data)
    {
        using (KoraContext db = new KoraContext())
        {
            var tdevice = db.Devices.Where(x => x.Id == data.DeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
            tdevice.Isbusy = "true"; // Gives a NullReferenceException.

            db.Processes.Add(data);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("index", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the controller action receiving this data?  What input does that controller action expect?  In your browser's debugging tools, when this form is submitted, what is the actual data being sent to that controller action?

Comment: @David I just added what the controller expects from the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a form with method="post" but your page model doesn't have OnPost method. You also need to add `[BindProperty]` attribute:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Device> devicelist { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public Process proclist { get; set; }
    public Extratime extras { get; set; }
    public Foodadd foods { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        devicelist = new List<Device>();
        proclist = new Process();
        extras = new Extratime();
        foods = new Foodadd();
    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        // do something with proclist
    }
}
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms

**Edit:**

You can add multiple OnPost handlers like this (Named Handler Methods):

```
public void OnPostAddTime()
{
    ...
}

public void OnPostAddFood()
{
    ...
}
```

And the forms:

```
<form asp-page-handler="addtime" method="post">
    ...
</form>
<form asp-page-handler="addfood" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: Can i have an OnPost function for each form in my view? plus i just added what my controller is expecting for more prespective.

Comment: Why do you have Controller if you are using razor pages?

Comment: That's what i used to do in mvc framework, I can move the function to the ViewModel but can i have multiple posts inside OnPost() ?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple OnPost handlers, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the way of using `Razor Page`. In `Razor Page`, There is no `Controller` in Backstage, So if you want to set `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` action, you need to set the method name like `OnGetxxxx` and `OnPostxxx`(xxx is method Name), Then if you want to pass model between `PageModel` and `View`, You need to add `[BindProperty]`, So in your PageModel, You need to change the code like:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Device> devicelist { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Process proclist { get; set; }
    public Extratime extras { get; set; }
    public Foodadd foods { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
       devicelist = new List<Device>();
       proclist = new Process();
       extras = new Extratime();
       foods = new Foodadd();
   }

    public IActionResult OnPostAddTime()
    {
        using (KoraContext db = new KoraContext())
        {
            var tdevice = db.Devices.Where(x => x.Id == proclist.DeviceId).FirstOrDefault();
            tdevice.Isbusy = "true"; // Gives a NullReferenceException.

            db.Processes.Add(proclist);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToPage(xxxxxxx);
        }
    }

}
```

Then in the view, You can use `asp-page-handler=xxx` to specify whtich method you want to submit.

More information you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).